# How to update installed .NET SDKs?

Tags: .net

`dotnet --info` shows installed sdks:

[image]

Now I would like to update them/add new. Is there a command for that?

Currently I am using Visual Studio Installer for that.

### EDIT Sep 2023

[Apparently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&tabs=net70#install-with-windows-package-manager-winget) you can also use winget tool to manage the sdks.

> winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options.

- Download and update directly from the web: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks
- Do what you're doing... use Visual Studio's installer

If you're asking for a `dotnet` CLI way of doing it (maybe for DevOps or automated scenarios), there is not a way to do that with `dotnet` itself. You can, however, do this, which uses scripting:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

There's [more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net50) for Windows based installation.

One nuance to your question: I don't think you can (or should) simply "upgrade"; you have to install. The reason, is the SDKs are designed to run side-by-side, so "upgrade" doesn't quite make sense.